# Trouble Getting Regex To Match With Line In SVN Log In Python

Tags: python, regex, svn, expression, match

this is only my second question posted on this site, but I read this site a lot.  Anyways, I'm having trouble getting a regex to match with a line in python.  What I am doing is I acquire a log from SVN and store it in svn_log.  I then go into a for loop reading the log line by line and trying to match it with a regex pattern, however it always returns with no matches.  Here is the for loop I am running:

```
#Scan each line until the changed paths are located.
pattern = re.compile(r"((M|A|D) /.+)")
changed_paths = []
    for line in svn_log:
        if pattern.match(line):
            # Save the changed paths in a list.
            changed_paths.append(line)
```

As my comments mention, I am trying to retrieve the changed paths from an SVN log.  The changed paths that I want start with an M, A, or D character.  Here is an example log that I am using to test this script with.

```
r14 | autobuild | 2016-12-27 16:22:21 -0800 (Tue, 27 Dec 2016) | 2 lines
Changed paths:
   M /trunk/src/board/ozmo.c
   M /trunk/src/ganymede/main.c
```

I am able to parse each line from this log and print it, but when I try to match my regex pattern with the last two lines, I get no matches, and nothing gets appended to my `changed_paths` variable.  I tried testing my regex using the following website: http://www.pyregex.com and it works there, just not in my script.  Let me know if you see anything wrong in my regex pattern or for loop.  Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

your are using [match instead of search](https://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html#search-vs-match). `match` only match at beginning of line, you need `search` or you can add `\s*` to the regex

```
line = '   M /trunk/src/board/ozmo.c'
pattern = re.compile(r"((M|A|D) /.+)")
pattern.search(line).group()
# 'M /trunk/src/board/ozmo.c'

# OR

pattern = re.compile(r"\s*((M|A|D) /.+)")
pattern.match(line).group()
```

the regex can be simplify to below using character set

```
pattern = re.compile(r"[MAD] (/.+)")
pattern.search(line).groups()[0]
# '/trunk/src/board/ozmo.c'
```

Comment: That worked!  I thought that by using `\s` that it would include all occurrences of whitespace before the character set, but what I needed was to include `\s*` to include all future occurrences of whitespace before the character set.  Thank you!